# Is there a shorter alternative to write "df <- df ％>%" in dplyr/tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

When I want to update the variable "df", I always write df twice as shown below.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(new column = 'new')
```

But I feel writing df twice is redundant and am wondering if there is a shorter alternative, something like

```
df <-> mutate(new column = 'new')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, use the `%<>%` operator from magrittr i.e. `df %<>% mutate(newcolumn = 'new')`

Comment: `df['new_column'] <-'new'`, `within(df, new_column <-'new')` etc

Answer (score 0):

As [akrun said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72622980/is-there-a-shorter-alternative-to-write-df-df-in-dplyr-tidyverse/76720618#comment128284257_72622980), the way of doing this is to use the assignment pipe, `%<>%`

The documentation can be found here:
https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/compound.html